# unable to convert java core dump to hprof with jmap

Tags: java, heap-dump, jmap

When trying to convert java core dump with jmap to hprof, i get this exection:

```
Attaching to core core.26045 from executable /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_21/bin/java, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 17.0-b16
Dumping heap to core.hprof ...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.runTool(JMap.java:179)
        at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.main(JMap.java:110)
Caused by: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.UnmappedAddressException
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.PageCache.checkPage(PageCache.java:208)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.PageCache.getData(PageCache.java:63)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerBase.readBytes(DebuggerBase.java:217)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal.readCInteger(LinuxDebuggerLocal.java:482)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerBase.readAddressValue(DebuggerBase.java:454)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal.readOopHandle(LinuxDebuggerLocal.java:436)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxAddress.getOopHandleAt(LinuxAddress.java:120)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.Oop.getKlassForOopHandle(Oop.java:237)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.ObjectHeap.newOop(ObjectHeap.java:362)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.HashtableEntry.literal(HashtableEntry.java:53)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.memory.SymbolTable.symbolsDo(SymbolTable.java:106)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.HeapHprofBinWriter.writeSymbols(HeapHprofBinWriter.java:838)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.HeapHprofBinWriter.write(HeapHprofBinWriter.java:396)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.HeapDumper.run(HeapDumper.java:56)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:221)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.HeapDumper.main(HeapDumper.java:77)
        ... 6 more
```

I used command:

```
jmap -dump:format=b,file=core.hprof /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_21/bin/java core.26045
```

Any help on this?

I am trying to create hprof in same box, where i got the core dump.